# Custom icon with a src of a folder in the project SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, svg, icons, sapui5, png

I want another icon that the icons that offer sap. I created a folder "images" with the image of the icon that I want (svg ang png)

I'm trying to do like this but doesn't work.

```
<core:Icon src="images/capsule.png" visible="{= ${Chora} === true}"></core:Icon>
```

Is possible use custom icons?

Comment: Your src is an image. Why don't you use the image element?

Comment: @Marc I tried but if it is an image is too much bigger. The icon adapts better, and in other project I did something similiar but inside a menuItem  <MenuItem text="{Landx}" key="{Land}" icon="images/Land.png"/> but I can't do this now because I need the property visible for the Icon

Comment: The SAPUI5 docs seem to indicate that you can only use an Icon from a font.

Comment: `sap.m.Image` has an inherited `visible` property, and you can set width and height. That should work, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sap.m.Image`:

```
    <Image src="images/capsule.png" 
           width="16px" height="16px"
           visible="{Chora}"/>
```

16px is a common Icon size; you can also use a different size, of course.

Comment: While we are at it, `{= ${Chora} === true}` is the same as `{Chora}`

Comment: @Marc true. I changed my answer accordingly.